# Rails 4 - has_one and has_many at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have the following setup:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

What I would like to do, is defining a `profile_photo` and a `cover_photo` for each album, but I'm not sure on how to approach the design.

First attempt has been to use `has_one :profile_photo, class: 'Photo'` with a migration creating a `albums.profile_photo_id` field and a `has_one :album` on the `Photo` model. Didn't work, as the SQL query generated was not correct:

```
> album.profile_photo

Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."album_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["album_id", 16]]

=> #<Photo id: 14, album_id: 16, image: "image_l.jpg", created_at: "2015-05-21 20:03:42", updated_at: "2015-05-21 20:03:42">
```

Another approach would be to add booleans to the `Photo` model, like `photos.is_profile_photo` and then on the class create a scoped association, but I feel this is not optimal as:

- I would have to take care of keeping album photos in sync so have only one with has the boolean value set to 1.
- Adds information to the photo table that couples it to the album one. If I want to have photos outside an album, they would have two extra fields `is_profile_photo` and `is_cover_photo` that would not make sense.

Is there a "Rails way" to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your use case, but have you looked at STI?  In case you are not familiar, [here](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) is a nice overview.

Comment: I don't think it's a complicated use case, just trying an Album model with a bunch of photos where two of them need to be marked as special (profile, and cover), Facebook style.

Not sure how STI would fit here though, feels excessive to have different classes for `ProfilePhoto` / `CoverPhoto` (if that's what you are suggesting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally gone with the second approach I mentioned.

```
class AddCoverAndProfileToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :is_profile, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :photos, :is_cover, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Album class:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :photos, inverse_of: :album, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :profile_photo,
    -> { where is_profile: true },
    class_name: 'Photo'

  has_one :cover_photo,
    -> { where is_cover: true },
    class_name: 'Photo'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true

  delegate :empty?, to: :photos

  validates_associated :photos

  def remove_profile_photo
    profile_photo.update(is_profile: false) if profile_photo.present?
  end

  def remove_cover_photo
    cover_photo.update(is_cover: false) if cover_photo.present?
  end

  def set_profile_photo(photo)
    remove_profile_photo
    photo.update(is_profile: true)
  end

  def set_cover_photo(photo)
    remove_cover_photo
    photo.update(is_cover: true)
  end
end
```

And finally Photo class:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader

  belongs_to :album
  validates_presence_of :image
  validates_presence_of :album

  validates_uniqueness_of :is_profile, scope: :album, if: :is_profile?
  validates_uniqueness_of :is_cover, scope: :album, if: :is_cover?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add 2 columns to the Album table

```
profile_photo_id
cover_photo_id
```

They would hold the id of the photo that was the profile and/or cover photo.

Then, in the Album model, you can easily add:

```
belongs_to :profile_photo, class_name: "Photo"
belongs_to :cover_photo, class_name: "Photo"
```

Then in the Photo model, you need:

```
has_many :profile_albums, class_name: "Album", foreign_key: "profile_photo_id"
has_many :cover_albums, class_name: "Album", foreign_key: "cover_photo_id"
```

(Note you can name them whatever you want, I picked these. You just need the class_name and foreign_key to point to the correct model with that id column)

Then you have the following associations:

> Album.profile_photo => returns the photo with ID in the Album
>
> Photo.profile_albums => returns all albums that have Photo as a profile picture

(the same applies to cover photo)

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, as stated in the question. Problem is that `has_one` expects a `belongs_to` on the other side on the relation, and the generated SQL query when doing `@album.profile_photo` checks for `photos.album_id` instead of the two columns that you mention.

Comment: I fixed it. So the association was backwards, you have a belongs_to in the album and has_many in the Photo. I've tested it with a quick rails app on my end, but let me know if it didn't work/make sense.